# get "logging.googleapis.com/billing/monthly_bytes_ingested" project info by gcloud or python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, metrics

I'd like to reach the following information via cli w/ gcloud or a script (bash/python/javascript).

**logging.googleapis.com/billing/monthly_bytes_ingested**

which can be found in the console under *Monitoring > Metrics Explorer > Logs-Based Metric > Monthly Log bytes ingested*   (pictured below)

While any answer would be great, I'd also like to know what you searched to find it.  I've read over docs for most of the day in both monitoring and logs and I don't seem to find clear programmatic approach to this data.  The closest I found was in the API here: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/list

[image]

Comment: I'm zeroing in on either:

[Reading Timeseries](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/reading-metrics#timeseries-list-names)

or using the console GUI MQL to put into a curl command...
[Metric Query Language](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/qn-from-api) via API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer extends the original question and answers it. Following the directions above, I use **jq** to sort the top value. So I get just the sum of the monthly log ingestion.

Why? It seems to be what I want when calling a metric called **monthly_bytes_ingested** is just the aggregated number. I do realize that this metric is under the timeseries area and so it is consistent with the timeseries notion to give rolling results. But, when I want a monthly total, do I want rolling or simply the greatest amount?

[referenced docs](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/qn-from-api#using-curl)

`query.json`

```json
{ "query": "fetch global
| metric 'logging.googleapis.com/billing/monthly_bytes_ingested'
| group_by 3h,
    [value_monthly_bytes_ingested_mean: mean(value.monthly_bytes_ingested)]
| every 3h
| group_by [],
    [value_monthly_bytes_ingested_mean_aggregate:
       aggregate(value_monthly_bytes_ingested_mean)] | within 4w" }
```

*I worked out the mql in the console*

`curl` + `jq`

```
curl -d @query.json -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \                                                                                                 [14:38:23]
--header "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST \
https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/${GCP_PROJECT}/timeSeries:query | jq '.timeSeriesData[].pointData | sort_by(.doubleValue) | .[-1]'
```

**sample result**

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "doubleValue": 39625036610082.664
    }
  ],
  "timeInterval": {
    "startTime": "2022-03-23T23:38:23.771566Z",
    "endTime": "2022-03-23T23:38:23.771566Z"
  }
}
```

Comment: Kindly post this as an answer for other user's reference.

Answer (score 1):

We are able to get output on our end using commands below.

**GCLOUD**

> > curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) "https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/$PROJECT_ID/timeSeries?interval.startTime=YYYY-MM-DDT13:45:46-05:00&interval.endTime=YYYY-MM-DD:05:06-05:00&filter="metric.type="logging.googleapis.com/billing/monthly_bytes_ingested"""

Kindly change the **Project_ID** and the **Interval Start/End** time.

You can refer on this documents for gcloud command.

[Google Cloud Monitoring Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-monitoring)

[Monitoring Filters](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/filters)

**PHYTON**

```
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3
import time

client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
project_name = "projects/$PROJECTID"
interval = monitoring_v3.TimeInterval()

now = time.time()
seconds = int(now)
nanos = int((now - seconds) * 10 ** 9)
interval = monitoring_v3.TimeInterval(
    {
        "end_time": {"seconds": seconds, "nanos": nanos},
        "start_time": {"seconds": (seconds - 5000), "nanos": nanos},
    }
)

results = client.list_time_series(
    request={
        "name": project_name,
        "filter": 'metric.type = "logging.googleapis.com/billing/monthly_bytes_ingested"',
        "interval": interval,
        "view": monitoring_v3.ListTimeSeriesRequest.TimeSeriesView.FULL,
    }
)
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

For more details and other code sample for **Reading Metric Data**, You can refer on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/samples/monitoring-read-timeseries-simple#code-sample).